# Maven : How to remove some files after project generation from an archetype?

Tags: maven-2

I'm creating a maven arechtype, which generates a project with java classes.

The archetype has some custom properties (requiredProperty in archetype-metadata.xml)
According to the user choices, some files will be useless (e.g database access classes if user don't wan't a database) so I will like to delete them.

Is it possible to run a cleanup hook script after generation?

Note : it would be even better to not include this files during the generation if the're not needded but I think it's not possible to declare some optional files right?

Thanks

Loïc

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the message:

> No post-archetype-generation goals to invoke.

in the generation and found this code: [IntegrationTestMojo.java](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/xref/org/apache/maven/archetype/mojos/IntegrationTestMojo.html)

where it seems that some rules may be described to be executed afterwards describing them in the "goals.txt" file

but can't figure our exactly what to include there